# Como obter o id do link presente no método postLink?

Tags: php, cakephp, formulário

Necessito de obter o `id` do link presente no método `postLink` para poder apagar da base de dados uma imagem cujo `id` seja igual a esse id do link, que é igual ao id da base de dados.
Como faço para obter esse valor?

**View**

```
    <h2>Apagar Fotografia</h2>
   <br>
   <table border="1" bordercolor="#e2e2e2"  width="720" style="word-wrap: break-word">
   <tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>

        <?php
            echo "<td style=text-align: justify>";
            //echo $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
            echo $this->Form->postLink('Apagar Fotografia', array('controller'=>'Gallery', 'action'=>'admin_del_image', $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['id'],/*'prefix'=>'admin'*/), array('class'=>'foto_del', 'title'=>'Apagar Fotografia'), __('Tem a certeza que quer apagar esta Fotografia?'));
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            //$src3 =$this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
            echo $this->Html->image('gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => '200px', 'height' => '133px', 'alt' => $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] )); 
            echo "</td>";
            $i++;
            if($i==2){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
                $i=0;   
            }
        ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
```

**Controller**

```
    public function admin_del_image(){
        $this->layout = 'admin_index';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
        $this->GalleryImage->id=$id;

        $gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);

        if($this->request->is('post')){

        if(!$this->GalleryImage->exists()){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Fotografia inválida'));
        }
        //$this->request->onlyAllow('post','delete');

        $options = array('conditions' => array('GalleryImage.' .$this->GalleryImage->primaryKey=>$id));
        $gallery_image_delete=$this->GalleryImage->find('first', $options);

        if(file_exists(WWW_ROOT. "img/gallery/" .$gallery_image_delete['GalleryImage']['path'])){
            unlink(WWW_ROOT . "img/gallery/" .$gallery_image_delete['GalleryImage']['path']);
            $this->GalleryImage->delete();
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Fotografia excluída com sucesso'));
        }
        else{
            $this->Session-setFlash(__('ERRO!, esta Fotografia não existe'));
        }
        $this->redirect($this->refere());}
 }
```

**Output**

```
    <td style="text-align:" justify=""><form action="/html/PushUp_app/Gallery/admin_del_image/25" name="post_5330531636e39982291469" id="post_5330531636e39982291469" style="display:none;" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"></form><a href="#" class="foto_del" title="Apagar Fotografia" onclick="if (confirm(&quot;Tem a certeza que quer apagar esta Fotografia?&quot;)) { document.post_5330531636e39982291469.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Apagar Fotografia</a></td>
    <td><img src="/html/PushUp_app/img/gallery/PushUp.png" width="200px" height="133px" alt="PushUp.png"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Duvída

Seu controller se chama `Gallery`? Porém você quer excluir uma `GalleryImage`?

Ai temos duas opções:

- Ou seu controller deve ser alterado para `Galleries`
- Ou deve criar um controller `GalleryImages`

Enfim, digo isso só para seguir as boas práticas.

## Seu `postLink` está incorreto

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(
  $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'],
  array(
    'controller' =>'Gallery',
    'action'=>'admin_del_image'
  ),
  array(
    'id'=> $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['id']
  ),
  "tem a certeza que quer apagar esta Fotografia?");
```

No seu caso, você passou o **id do link** como o **id da GalleryImage**. E com isso, a sua action não irá conseguir prosseguir com a requisição. *(Ou talvez você tenha tratado de outra forma, que não esteja descrita na questão...)*

O correto deve ser:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->postLink(
  'Excluir Imagem',
  array(
    'action' => 'del_image',
    $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['id'],
    'prefix' => 'admin'
  ),
  array(
    'class' => 'classe-que-voce-deseja',
    'title' => 'Excluir Imagem'
  ),
  __('Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?')); ?>
```

## Altere a sua action

Siga o modelo abaixo (*não precisa usar o exato código que eu fiz, é apenas um modelo pra você ter uma base*):

```
/**
 * admin_del_image method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException     
 */
public function admin_del_image($id)
{

  // Como não sei qual model você está usando, pois o nome
  // do controller é diferente, não vou fazer o loadModel() aqui

  // Seta o id e verifica se a imagem existe
  $this->GalleryImage->id = $id;
  if (!$this->GalleryImage->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Image inválida'));
  }

  // valida se a requisição foi feita por POST ou DELETE (method)
  // caso contrário retorna MethodNotAllowed
  $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');

  // Configura as opções para buscar pela imagem (first = limit 1)
  $options = array('conditions' => array('GalleryImage.' . $this->GalleryImage->primaryKey => $id));
  $galleryImage = $this->GalleryImage->find('first', $options);

  // Verifica se a imagem existe no diretório especificado
  if(file_exists(WWW_ROOT . "diretorio-da-sua-imagem-aqui/" . $galleryImage['GalleryImage']['path'])) {

    // exclui a imagem
    unlink(WWW_ROOT . "diretorio-da-sua-imagem-aqui/" . $galleryImage['GalleryImage']['path']);

    // exclui o registro
    $this->GalleryImage->delete();

    // mensagem da sessão
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Imagem excluída com sucesso'));

  } else {

    // Se não encontrou a imagem no disco, retorna a mensagem de erro
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Esta imagem não existe'));

  }

  // Redireciona para a página anterior
  $this->redirect($this->referer());

}
```

---

### [EDIT]

Quanto ao erro descrito nos comentários, é por conta **da sua action** e **pela ausência do `$id`**.

Neste caso, sua action está assim:

```
public function admin_del_image(){
```

Mas deve ficar assim:

```
public function admin_del_image($id){
```

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Qualquer dúvida, deixe um comentário abaixo.

Comment: Peço desculpa pela demora, mas em casa não tenho acesso á net. Já efectuei várias alterações ao código, e tenho algumas questões relativamente ás suas sugestões. Ao clicar no postLink, obtenho um erro `Error: The requested address '/html/PushUp_app/Gallery/admin_del_image/25?url=Gallery%2Fadmin_del_image%2F25' was not found on this server.`, o 25 remete para o id da imagem na base de dados, além da mensagem flash que indica "Fotografia inválida", do `notFoundException`, assim como se eu colocar o `if($this->request->is('post'))`. Não falta atribuir um valor ao `$id`?

Comment: @SunT Neste erro o CakePHP está dizendo que: **não existe** no controller **Gallery** (que o nome já está incorreto), a action **admin_del_image**. Existe? Ou não? Ou está em outro controller? Se estiver em outro controller, adicione no **array da rota do postLink()** o valor: `'controller' => 'GalleryImages'`. Se puder, crie um Gist (gist.github.com) com todos os arquivos relacionados pra mim.